# Bootstrapper does not load my NinjectModules

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, ninject, bootstrapper

I am trying to use [Bootstrapper with Ninject](http://bootstrapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Ninject%20Extension). I have installed `Ninject.MVC3` to initialize my Ninject container from nuget and I have created a test module like this:

```
public class TestNinjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<DBEntities>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
        Bind(typeof(IGenericRepository<>))
              .To(typeof(GenericRepository<>)).InRequestScope();
        Bind<ISystemRepository>().To<SystemRepository>().InRequestScope();
        Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
    }
}
```

I have also included the `Start()` call in my `Global.asax.cs`

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        Bootstrapper.With.Ninject().Start();
        Bootstrapper.With.AutoMapper().Start();
    }
}
```

However I still get an `ActivationException` from Ninject when a controller with dependency is called, signalling my `TestNinjectModule.Load()` method was not called. How can I solve that?

Exception Message:

> Error activating IUnitOfWork
>   No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
>   Activation path:
>     2) Injection of dependency IUnitOfWork into parameter unitOfWork of constructor of type > TreasurySystemController
>     1) Request for SystemController
>
> Suggestions:
>     1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IUnitOfWork.
>     2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into > the kernel.
>     3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
>     4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the >constructors parameter name.
>     5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are >correct.

Stack Trace:

> at Ninject.KernelBase.Resolve(IRequest request) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 359
>      at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service, IContext parent) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Targets\Target.cs:line 197
>      at Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Targets\Target.cs:line 165
>      at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:line 114
>      at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_2(ITarget target) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:line 96
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:line 96
>      at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Context.cs:line 157
>      at Ninject.KernelBase.<>c_*DisplayClass10.b*_c(IBinding binding) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 386
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectDependencyResolver.cs:line 56
>      at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)

Comment: '`ActivationException`' ... 'when a controller with dependency is called'... what exception ? what 'called' ? I think you might be jumping to premature conclusions. What happens if you put a breakpoint on `Load` ? What do you see when you examine the Kernel at the point at which the Activation is failing?

Comment: @RubenBartelink `ActivationException` is the exception thrown by Ninject when it cannot resolve the dependency. When I put breakpoints in my `Application_Start()` and `CreateKernel()` (in `NinjectWebCommon` class, created by installing `Ninject.MVC3` nuget package), there are **two** kernels being created, and only the one without my bindings was activated to resolve dependencies. That's why I am getting the exception

Comment: TL;DR - you didn't answer my questions which is why nobody has answered your question yet. I know what an ActivationException is and lots of others do do; my point is that a full StackTrace (it doesn't have to be 20 pages) and the Message adds a lot. The 2 kernels are for 2 HttpApplications. Is your Load() being hit? Is the failing resolve [that we dont have a stacktrace for] (when you tell the debugger to break on First Chance) happening against a Kernel with or without your bindings.

Comment: Updated with exception message and stack trace. My `Load()` method was hit but as I said it seems I have created two Ninject kernels in my application (not sure if that's correct or not) and only one of them is used to resolve my dependencies, which doesn't have the `NinjectModule` in it.

Comment: +1 Much better. There should be def 2 HttpApplications and associated kernels unless I'm mistaken (it's possible to share them but def not a good idea). Stack traces from `Kernel` ctor should let you know who is creating the other Kernel without the Load of your Module?

Comment: Because I have installed both `Ninject.MVC3` and `Bootstrapper.Ninject` nuget packages, I believe it's `Ninject.MVC3` that created an extra kernel without my modules. I have tried uninstalling this package. However the other kernel created with `Bootstrapper.With.Ninject().Start()` was not used to resolve my dependencies, thus leading to this `ActivationException`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution. By changing the implementation of `NinjectWebCommon` to:

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon 
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
    public static IKernel Kernel { get; private set; } // Expose the kernel through a property

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start() 
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        return Kernel = kernel;
    }
}
```

Then in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        Bootstrapper.With.AutoMapper().Start();
        Bootstrapper.With.Ninject()
            .WithContainer(NinjectWebCommon.Kernel) // Use the kernel inside NinjectWebCommon instead of creating a new one
            .Start();
    }
}
```

Then all classes deriving from `NinjectModule` will have their `Load()` methods called.